# using sed with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want it to detect the following pattern in FILE_1:

```
STRING_1   :   "STRING_2"
```

and append STRING_2 to FILE_2

This is what I have right now:

```
sed 's/STRING_1\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g' FILE_1 >> FILE_2;
```

but this doesn't work, it appends a lot of random stuff to FILE_2(that are not supposed to match). Not sure what I did wrong ...

Comment: Can you give an example of the input where it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a risk to answer by changing the question spec but...

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if ( /.*STRING_1\s*:\s*\"([^"]*)\".*/)' FILE_1 >> FILE_2
```

appears to work fine

Answer (score 1):

If there is text before `STRING_1` and after `STRING_2` , it'll not be removed with your current regex and hence will get appended to `FILE_2`.

To fix this add `.*` at the beginning and at the end of your current pattern as:

```
sed 's/.*STRING_1\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/g' FILE_1 >> FILE_2;
       ^^                          ^^
```

Comment: That means your regex is not working. Give us some sample lines of your input.

Answer (score 0):

changed it to:

```
sed 's/.*STRING_1\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/g' FILE_1 >> FILE_2;
```

but it still appends the whole file instead of the regex match

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed -n` if you don't want `sed` to output each line by default and the `p` modifier to print the result of a match.

```
sed -n -e 's/foo/bar/gp' FILE_1 >> FILE_2
```